# after doing git push heroku master should we do git push origin master

Tags: git, github

I asked this question because my commit is not showing up in github after doing `git push heroku master` but it showed up after doing `git push origin master`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command will give you:

```
git remote -v

heroku  https://git.heroku.com/MY_PROJECT.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/MY_PROJECT.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:<name>/MY_PROJECT.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:<name>/MY_PROJECT.git (push)
```

This means that you have two separate remotes (meaning different repositories in different places). One remote (`origin`) is on GitHub. The other (`heroku`) is on Heroku's servers.

So it makes perfect sense that if you take your code and push it to the heroku git repository, through `git push heroku master`, for that code to be published to Heroku. Heroku and GitHub are not together, thus they need to be updated individually, as you found it through the two separate push commands.

Keep in mind that the general format of `git push` is -> `git push <options> <repository> <refspec>`